# Make sure that my local SMTP server uses the orginal gateway

Tags: email, iis, vpn, smtp

I have a server that connects via VPN to another server. Over this connection my application does it's work. But, that same application has to send emails as well. It has to do this via the local IIS SMTP server.

The problem is that the VPN connection doesn't allow mail traffic. So i have to make sure that the emails are send over my 'normal internet connection'.

Can anyone help me how to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do in this case is to disable the "Use default gateway on remote network" option on the VPN connection, do so by following these steps:

1. Go to properties of the VPN connection
2. In the Networking tab select "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)" properties
3. Click Advanced
4. Uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network"

This will tell Windows to use your local gateway for all communication, the VPN will be used when your server wants to communicate to a server in the VPN network.

Hope this helps.